# Second table value not submitted Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) code error

Tags: php, arrays

This password registration script should pass two sets of values: one set to a `user` table and a mobile phone entry to the second, `user_info` table.

First set of values (`name`, `email`, `password`) are being inserted into the `user` table, but mobile phone number is not being inserted into the `user_info` table.

The script stops short of returning the *"User Registered"* and *"Added User Meta Information"* messages instead returning this error

> ```
> Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
> ```

I have tried to debug the arrays and code around it but to no avail. Appreciate any help!

Thanks

````
```
        <?php 
        session_start();
        require_once('includes/connect.php');
        require_once('if-loggedin.php');
        include('includes/header.php');
        if(isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST)){
            // PHP Form Validations
            if(empty($_POST['username'])){ $errors[]="User Name field is Required"; }else{
    // Check Username is Unique with DB query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?";
    $result = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute(array($_POST['username']));
    $count = $result->rowCount();
    if($count == 1){
        $errors[] = "User Name already exists in database";
    }
            }
if(empty($_POST['email'])){ $errors[]="E-mail field is Required"; }else{
    // Check Email is Unique with DB Query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?";
    $result = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute(array($_POST['email']));
    $count = $result->rowCount();
    if($count == 1){
        $errors[] = "E-Mail already exists in database";
    }
            }
            if(empty($_POST['mobile'])){ $errors[]="Mobile field is Required"; }



            if(empty($_POST['password'])){ $errors[]="Password field is Required"; }else{
    // check the repeat password
    if(empty($_POST['passwordr'])){ $errors[]="Repeat Password field is Required"; }else{
        // compare both passwords, if they match. Generate the Password Hash
        if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['passwordr']){
            // create password hash
            $pass_hash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        }else{
            // Display Error Message
            $errors[] = "Both Passwords Should Match";
                    }
                }
            }

            // CSRF Token Validation
            if(isset($_POST['csrf_token'])){
    if($_POST['csrf_token'] === $_SESSION['csrf_token']){
    }else{
        $errors[] = "Problem with CSRF Token Validation";
    }
            }
            // CSRF Token Time Validation
            $max_time = 60*60*24; // in seconds
            if(isset($_SESSION['csrf_token_time'])){
                $token_time = $_SESSION['csrf_token_time'];
    if(($token_time + $max_time) >= time() ){
    }else{
        $errors[] = "CSRF Token Expired";
        unset($_SESSION['csrf_token']);
        unset($_SESSION['csrf_token_time']);
    }
            }

// If no Errors, Insert the Values into users table
if(empty($errors)){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (:username, :email, :password)";
    $result = $db->prepare($sql);
    $values = array(':username'     => $_POST['username'],
                    ':email'        => $_POST['email'],
                    ':password'     => $pass_hash
                    );
    $res = $result->execute($values);
    if($res){
        $messages[] = "User Registered";
        // get the id from last insert query and insert a new record into user_info table with mobile             
        number
        $userid = $db->lastInsertID();
        $uisql = "INSERT INTO user_info (uid, mobile) VALUES (:uid, :mobile)";
        $uiresult = $db->prepare($uisql);
        $values = array(':uid'          => $userid,
                        ':mobile'       => $_POST['mobile']
                        );
        $uires = $uiresult->execute($values) or die(print_r($result->errorInfo(), true));
        if($uires){
            $messages[] = "Added User Meta Information";
        }

    }
   }
   }
        // CSRF Protection
        // 1. Create CSRF token
        $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
        $_SESSION['csrf_token'] = $token;
        $_SESSION['csrf_token_time'] = time();

        // 2. add CSRF token to form
        // 3. check the CSRF token on form submission
        ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">user Registered and Added User Meta 
                <h3 class="panel-title">Please Register</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <?php
                    if(!empty($errors)){
                        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>";
                        foreach ($errors as $error) {
                            echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>&nbsp;".$error."            
             <br>";
                        }
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                ?>
                <?php
                    if(!empty($messages)){
                        echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>";
                        foreach ($messages as $message) {
                            echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span>&nbsp;".$message." 
        <br>";
                        }
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                ?>
                <form role="form" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" name="username"             
    type="text" autofocus value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])){ echo $_POST['username']; } ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" 
     type="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])){ echo $_POST['email']; } ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile" name="mobile" 
       type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['mobile'])){ echo $_POST['mobile']; } ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" 
          type="password" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Repeat Password" 
 name="passwordr" type="password" value="">
                        </div>
                        <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block"                         
    value="Register" />
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
        </div>
        <?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
````

Comment: `$uiresult->errorInfo()` instead of `$result->errorInfo()` on second call

Comment: Code is hard to follow with the erratic indentations. Also seems like a lot of redundant checks here.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion. It works now. Look at that many times and missed it.